# searching with Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

I'm at an impasse that probably has a simple solution, but I can't see it. I've done everything in the Sphinx documentation up to the point of the [Quick Tour](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.6/quick-tour.html), but when I test the search using test.php in PuTTy, it returns zero results.

I've put in all my correct database info in sphinx.conf and I've assembled the SQL query. I'm not getting any errors at all, just that it says it's returning 0 results every time I search.

Is it looking at my databases? Let me know if you need to see any code. searchd is running (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx has 2 different phases:

1) Indexing

2) Searching

I belive from your question that you skipped by mistake part where you need to index data (run indexer) so searching would have data to search through. In indexing part sphinx will take all of data from your db and search will actually be searching that and not your DB.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that indexer --all showing that it found and indexed actual documents.

Besides the API there is another convenient method to test sphinx using SphinxQL

Add line "listen = 9306:mysql41" line in searchd section in sphinx.conf as described in http://astellar.com/2011/12/replacing-mysql-full-text-search-with-sphinx/ and start the daemon.

Then run

```
mysql -h0 -P 9306
```

and then fire the query against sphinx

```
SELECT * FROM <your_sphinx_index>;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply! I'll check out all this and anything else that this stuff makes me think of and let you know if I need any more help!